# PHP Carbon format to New Date() on Javascript

Tags: php, html, laravel, php-carbon

I want my website changed to full server-side, or with little client-side. What format was used by Carbon to Javascript Date object?
Something like this?

```
Wed Feb 23 2022 12:46:13 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time)
```

Comment: You can parse datetime string using this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [read](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-serialization) here for Carbon documentation, and you can format Carbon instance whatever you like

```
Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I read it too, but only focus on the Common Formats section XD. I will read the whole documentation from now.

Comment: You're welcome, you can use json format etc. in Carbon too, or just use simple Ymd His format and parse it in frontend, or if you are using Laravel as your api just send it and parse it in the frontend.

Comment: Be careful the `Y-m-d H:i:s` does not include the timezone, You should use `toJSON` to get a UTC string so whatever the timezone is server-side, the converted to UTC then converted back to browser timezone when you pass it to `new Date()` So 10:00 Chicago time will become 17:00 Berlin time (which is correct), if you don't have the timezone in your export, you'll get 10:00 Berlin time in the browser which would be wrong.